# Выборка из нескольких таблиц inner join

Tags: sql, sqlite

Имеется структура БД следующего вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо сделать выборку из таблицы Drivers(date, pack, directory) и Usable(system). При написании запроса у меня(скорее всего) где-то декартово произведение, ибо выдаётся большое количество строк - дубликатов. Использование distinct проблему решает, удаляя дубликаты, и я получаю нужный результат, однако я и сам понимаю, что это жутки костыль и так делать не нужно. Ниже приведён текст моего запроса, посмотрите, может быть я делаю очевидную ошибку:

```
select Drivers.pack Drivers.directory, Drivers.[date], Usable.[system]
from Sections inner join Drivers
on
(
    Drivers.id in 
   (
        select driverId from Sections where Sections.id in 
       (
           select sectionId from Usable where deviceId in 
           (
                select id from Devices where deviceId like "%VEN_14F1%" and deviceId like "%DEV_8880%"
           )
        )
    )
    and Drivers.id = Sections.driverId
)
inner join Usable
on
(
     Usable.[system] = "6.1x64"
     and
     Usable.sectionId = Sections.id
)
order by(Drivers.[date]) desc;
```

Подскажите решение.
P.S.: код отформатировал, надеюсь, так будет удобнее читать.

UPD:

```
SELECT
    Drivers.date,
    Drivers.pack,
    Drivers.directory,
    Usable.system
FROM
    Drivers
INNER JOIN Sections ON Drivers.id = Sections.driverId
INNER JOIN Usable ON Sections.id = Usable.sectionId
inner join Devices on Usable.deviceId = Devices.id
WHERE Devices.deviceId LIKE "%VEN_14F1%" AND Devices.deviceId LIKE "%DEV_8880%" AND Usable.system = '6.1x64'
order by(Drivers.[date]) desc;
```

Comment: Да, у вас декартово произведение в первом join. Фактически к любой записи из Sections берутся все записи из Drivers подходящие по условию, а не только те, которые связаны именно с данной записью Sections. Потому что в условиях объединения отсутствует условие для их прямого объединения. А подзапрос срабатывает для всех записей вне зависимости от того относятся они друг к другу или нет.

Comment: @Mike я обновил вопрос, добавив изменённый запрос, проверив его, вроде бы он составлен правильно, однако он вновь выдаёт копии..

Comment: Он может выдавать копии по целому ряду причин. например у вас в таблице Sections нет уникального ключа из полей DriverId, id и тогда у вас там могут оказаться две записи связывающие между собой одни и те же записи Drivers и Usabe. и на выходе разумеется будет две записи. Или к одному Drivers у вас есть несколько разных Usabe но во всех одинаковое поле system и тогда опять же вы видите несколько с виду одинаковых записей. Так что выведите другие поля из разных таблиц что бы на дублях определить что же у них разного, устраивает ли вас это и можно ли их подавлять distinct

Comment: Спасибо, в БД действительно много копий, отличающихся другими полями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование группировки решает проблему:

```
group by (Drivers.directory)
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте:

```
SELECT
    Drivers.date,
    Drivers.pack,
    Drivers.directory,
    Usable.system
FROM
    Drivers
INNER JOIN Sections ON Drivers.id = Sections.driverId
INNER JOIN Usable ON Sections.id = Usable.sectionId
WHERE
    Usable.deviceId LIKE "%VEN_14F1%" AND Usable.deviceId LIKE "%DEV_8880%" AND Usable.system = '6.1x64'
```

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, только сейчас заметил что используете SQLite. Видимой мой запрос вряд ли подойдёт.

Comment: В вашем запросе не используется ни одного элемента, который бы выходил за пределы стандарта SQL92 так что он просто обязан работать на любой SQL-СУБД, включая SQLite

Comment: Спасибо, однако теперь запрос не выдаёт результатов :(

Comment: Должен был выдавать. Но я как вижу Вы справились с задачей)